# Proper way to pass configuration into Redux action creators

Tags: javascript, configuration, redux, redux-thunk

What is considered the "Redux" way of **injecting configuration into action creators**?

Consider an async action creator:

```
export function login(username, password) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const service = Auth.createService(config); // <- that's the one

        service.login(username, password).then((data) => {
            const {token} = data;
            dispatch(success(token));
        }).catch((err) => {
            Logger.log(err);
        });
    };
}
```

As you can see - `AuthService` (and all other services) require some configuration, that normally defines things like: `baseUrl`, `headers` and more.

Having them `require`d in the `AuthService` itself via something like:

```
import configfrom '../config/globalConfig`;
```

is sub-optimal for multitude of reasons and **doesn't let you override them for a specific service instance**.

Using a middleware (some extension over `redux-thunk`) would provide the ability to inject the configuration, but:

1. it is most likely already injected via `getState`, since, to me, configuration is a part of the application state, especially if it is editable
2. it **still wouldn't allow overrides** on per-creator basis

Passing the configuration, from container components, to the action creator directly `this.props.dispatch(login(username, password, config));`, to me, is extremely verbose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this [`injectMiddleware`](https://github.com/este/este/blob/6a7304693c594d0502eabe32f87ac0475830fe7d/src/common/configureStore.js#L28-L32) from Este is fairly neat:

```
// Like redux-thunk with dependency injection.
const injectMiddleware = deps => ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action =>
  next(typeof action === 'function'
    ? action({ ...deps, dispatch, getState })
    : action
  );
```

This lets you write action creators like

```
export function login(username, password) {
   return ({ dispatch, getState, authService }) => {
```

and inject `authService` while initializing the middleware.